# Initializing Structures in C - Avoiding segmentation faults

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization

I am new to C and have a question about initializing a structure.  I am using a structure that I have not created and so I don't know what is inside of it.  Therefore, I did not initialize it but the compiler complained.  So I set it equal to NULL but I got a segmentation fault.  Then I looked up how to set everything to 0 and it said to set it equal to {0}.  That too gave me a segmentation fault.  Since I know the function I am calling is correct, and that the array I pass it is of the correct size, I am almost certain it has something to do with the way I initialize the structure.  The initialization is

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = {0}
```

The header for the function is

```
void aes_setkey(aes_ctx *aes, const void *key, u_int len);
```

The way that I am calling it is

```
aes_setkey(aes_struct, aes, CCA_STRENGTH);
```

where aes is a buffer of size 16, CCA_STRENGTH is a constant int of 16.

To sum up the problem, I think that the way that I initialize the structure causes it to be unusable later on.  Any help that can be given to me on this would be so appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: The key point is that your code does not allocate a struct, it allocated a pointer to a struct. That's what you need to concentrate on understanding before you move on to initialization.

Comment: http://www.scs.stanford.edu/nyu/05sp/lab/lab1.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize a *pointer* that way (well, you can, it just doesn't point to anythign valid).  Something like this is what you are after:

```
struct aes_ctx aes_struct = {0};
```

You can then pass the address of `aes_struct` to the function, but that depends on whether or not you need to dynamically allocate this thing (required scope and the size of the type will dictate this).

So...

```
struct aes_ctx aes_struct = {0};
aes_setkey(&aes_struct, aes, CCA_STRENGTH);
```

Or

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct aes_ctx));
/* you may want to initialize the structure via memset or some init function */
aes_setkey(aes_struct, aes, CCA_STRENGTH);
```

Comment: `struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = {0}` is perfectly valid C, see my answer.

Comment: @ouah: Right, unless you want to, you know, actually use the thing.  You're technically correct of course, 0 is a valid value, but I tried to answer the spirit of the question, which was telling the OP how to do it right.  The function he is calling expects a valid pointer.

Comment: you missed my point. A lot of people believe that `T *p = {0}`  form is not valid when then enclosing braces are present and I wanted to make clear that this is perfectly valid. The comment was not for the OP but in response to your answer.

Comment: @ouah: I don't think I missed it at all... *"You're technically correct of course, 0 is a valid value"*.  The problem is that it is not extremely useful information as the function expects a valid pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that you're not initializing a structure, but a *pointer*. This means that what you're doing is setting the pointer to be an invalid address, which causes a seg fault when it tries to access that address. You either need to allocate memory:

```
struct aes_ctx* aes_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct aes_ctx));
```

or create the actual struct (not a pointer) and pass the address:

```
struct aes_ctx aes_struct = {0};
aes_setkey(&aes_struct, aes, CCA_STRENGTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not allocating memory for the pointer to point to.  You can use either

```
struct aes_ctx aes_struct = {0};  // Declare the struct, not a pointer to it
aes_setkey(&aes_struct, aes, CCA_STRENGTH);
```

Or, if you want to allocate the memory dynamically,

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct aes_ctx));
memset(aes_struct, 0, sizeof(struct aes_ctx); // Only if you need to zero the data
aes_setkey(aes_struct, aes, CCA_STRENGTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = {0};
```

By doing so you are actually initializing the `aes_struct` pointer to `0`.

The two initializations:

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = {0};
```

and

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = 0;
```

are equivalent. C says you can add optional `{}` when initializing a scalar. So basically you are not initializing your pointer to a structure with members initialized to zero but you are initializing the pointer with a null pointer constant.

Although, you can perform the former in one shot using compound literals:

```
struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = (struct aes_ctx) {0};
```

Comment: Your last two lines confuse me. How is that different from a simple `struct aes_ctx *aes_struct = 0;`? You're still not allocating memory for it.

Comment: `(){}` is the compound literal operator (introduced in c99). In my last example, the pointer points to a structure object with members initialized to `0`. While in my other examples, the pointer does not point to any structure object: the pointer value is a null pointer constant.

Comment: So does it point to a struct on the stack then or is there some malloc magic going on?

Comment: @BrendanLong the structure object is in the stack (more precisely it has automatic storage duration) if `aes_struct` initialization is done inside a function.

Comment: This is not extremely helpful to the OP.  It does not show him how to solve his problem, it simply shows that you can assign 0 to a pointer.  Often times you have to look beyond the obvious to give a useful answer to a beginner.

Comment: @EdS. Did you read the last line? It is exactly what the OP wanted to achieve but he incorrectly used a null pointer constant.

Comment: @ouah: Why would you do that at all?  I can't imagine writing that instead of just declaring it as a local variable and passing the address or `malloc`ing one.